# Testing if user has liked my page in angulike

Tags: angularjs, facebook-like

Hi I am using the Angular plugin "angulike". I would like to test whether a user has liked my page or not. If he does not something should pop up.

Which way is the best to test whether user has liked my page?

A thought: I thought about testing for css classes. They are different in the two cases, but it not seem to be the best approach

Answer (score 0):

Incentivizing likes is not allowed anymore, and not possible. You would need to authorize a user with the `user_likes` permission to get his Page likes, and Facebook will not approved it in the [review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review) process just for that.